# How to add a Step in Amazon EMR using Step Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, aws-step-functions

I am new at creating Step function in AWS. I have created a EMR cluster and would like to add a step to it.. I'm using the command below:

```
 "Next": "Run first step"
    },
    "Run first step": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::elasticmapreduce:addStep.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "ClusterId.$": "$.cluster.ClusterId",
        "Step": {
          "Name": "Run Data Transformation",
          "ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE",
          "HadoopJarStep": {
            "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
            "Args": [
              "spark-submit s3://xdam-nyctaxi-emr-research/scripts/nyctaxi-tranform-task.py s3://xdam-nyctaxi-emr-research/data/nyctaxi-raw/nyc_taxi_trip_duration.csv s3://xdam-nyctaxi-emr-research/data/nyctaxi-transformed/"
            ]
```

Checking on my EMR cluster the step argument should look like this:
[image]

Instead it fails because the created step argument has quotes in it:
[image]

How could I pass the argument without the quotes?

Comment: which library or platform you are using to submit this job/step?

Answer (score 2):

The spark-submit in `Args` array should not be a one long string put in array formst like below.

```
 'Args': [
                '/usr/bin/spark-submit',
                'you_script.py'
                's3://your_path',
                's3://your_path'
  ]
```

You can pass spark-submit command's own argument in order or by name with providing double-dash followed by the name (  --<argument_name> ) as the preceding array element before the value.